# Express API Call Angular 6 no data

Tags: angular, api

I'm trying to display the results from my localhost express server on my angular front-end. I am not getting any results in my html and am trying to figure out why?

on localhost:3000/yelp I see my results, for the sake of space i'll only post the first few rows:

> {"businesses": [{"id": "YzUVUMzeiMVeufW2eOC0FQ", "alias": "howdy-homemade-ice-cream-dallas", "name": "Howdy Homemade Ice Cream", "image_url": "https://s3-media3.fl.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/S21rwytsz7y6pMBt9V82ig/o.jpg", "is_closed": false, "url": "https://www.yelp.com/biz/howdy-homemade-ice-cream-dallas?adjust_creative=FLKfJRyWD2HUQxXlozzc5A&utm_campaign=yelp_api_v3&utm_medium=api_v3_business_search&utm_source=FLKfJRyWD2HUQxXlozzc5A", "review_count": 153, "categories": [{"alias": "desserts", "title": "Desserts"}, {"alias": "icecream", "title": "Ice Cream & Frozen Yogurt"}], "rating": 4.5, "coordinates": {"latitude": 32.8509351, "longitude": -96.8095341}, "transactions": [], "price": "$", "location": {"address1": "4333 Lovers Ln", "address2": "", "address3": "", "city": "Dallas", "zip_code": "75225", "country": "US", "state": "TX", "display_address": ["4333 Lovers Ln", "Dallas, TX 75225"]}, "phone": "+14699308494", "display_phone": "(469) 930-8494", "distance": 1555.5657355032201}, {"id": "KP0pkPt74B1jPZFyAXcrZQ", "alias": "milk-and-cream-dallas-2", "name": "Milk & Cream", "image_url": "https://s3-media1.fl.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/1bUcZ7uATp7gKjsXA7hHkQ/o.jpg", "is_closed": false, "url": "https://www.yelp.com/biz/milk-and-cream-dallas-2?adjust_creative

I have my **list.model.ts** as

```
    export interface List {
    id: string;
    name?: string;
    rating?: number;
    review_count?: number;
    url?: string;
    location: string;
    display_name?: string;
    image_url?: string;
    is_closed?: boolean;
}
```

my **list.service.ts** is as follows:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable, Subject, asapScheduler, pipe, of, from, interval, merge, fromEvent, SubscriptionLike, PartialObserver } from 'rxjs';
import { List } from '../models/list.model';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
@Injectable()
export class ListService {

    constructor(private http: Http) { }

    private serverApi = 'http://localhost:3000';

    public getAllLists(): Observable<List[]> {

        const URI = `${this.serverApi}/yelp/`;
        return this.http.get(URI)
            .pipe(map(res => res.json()))
            .pipe(map(res => <List[]>res.lists))
    }
}
```

and my **results-page.component.html** is as follows:

```
<table id="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Business Picture</th>
      <th>Business Name</th>
      <th>Description</th>
      <th> Scoops </th>

    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let list of lists">
      <td>{{list.location}}</td>
      <td>{{list.id}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**results-page.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ListService } from '../services/list.service';
import { List } from '../models/list.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-results-page',
  templateUrl: './results-page.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./results-page.component.css']
})
export class ResultsPageComponent implements OnInit {
  private lists: List[] = []; // creates a private variable of lists with type of model List an creates an empty array

  constructor(private listServ: ListService) { };

  ngOnInit() {

    this.loadLists(); //  loads all lists on init
  }

  public loadLists() {
    // get all lists from server and update lists property
    this.listServ.getAllLists().subscribe(response => this.lists = response, )
  }
}
```

and last but not least my **app.component.ts** is as follows:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { HttpClientModule, HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NavbarComponent } from './navbar/navbar.component';
import { ResultsPageComponent } from './results-page/results-page.component';
import { SplashComponent } from './splash/splash.component';
import { ListService } from './services/list.service';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NavbarComponent,
    ResultsPageComponent,
    SplashComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,HttpModule,HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [ListService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, there are a few things going on here.  First, this seems to be an incomplete example.  It would be helpful to see your results-page.component.ts to have a look at where you are actually calling the getAllLists method and how your are trying put the results of that request into your template. It also appears that the interface you provided doesn't show the List type as having any of the properties (category, title, description) that you are trying to access in your template .  In any case, here is a simple stackblitz illustrating how to make an HTTP request (using HttpClient, not Http), subscribe to the response, and then put the results into a variable that can be accessed in your template.

Of course, if you try to access properties that are not present on the response objects, you will get an error.  I'm just not sure if you're typing is incorrect or what.  I will try to provide additional guidance if you leave a comment.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3ywm9x

Comment: Apologies for that not sure how I missed those two things. I had updated the HTML in my code but not on here. I've updated that above and will take a look at the link you provided. Thank you for the help!

Comment: No problem.  Looking at the code you put up, I don't think you can access private properties in the component template, even the template associated with the component the property is declared in.  Just FYI - HttpClient is the new standard library to use with Angular as of version 5, I believe.  Among other things, it removes the necessity of piping to the map operator just to get the response into JSON.

Comment: If this does end up helping you out/solving your problem, I would appreciate it if you would upvote my response and accept it as the answer.  Thanks!

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I finally had time to look at your code on stackblitz on my flight to Dallas. This actually worked perfectly thank you so much for the help ace. I unfortunately can't upvote due to my low rep but I did select your answer as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public getAllLists(): Observable<List[]> {

        const URI = `${this.serverApi}/yelp/`;
        return this.http.get(URI)
            .pipe(map(res => res.json()),
             map(res => <List[]>res.businesses));
    }
```

You JSON doesn't have an attribute `lists`, you should use instead `businesses`.